# Set a Default branch on a TFS 2017 Hosted Repository

Tags: git, tfs

Been banging my head around on this one. All I'm trying to do is set the a branch on the hosted TFS *git* repo to be ***default*** via the command line.

From what I can tell there's no obvious way to do this directly against the hosted repo, however in my case, since I'll end of scripting this, I have no objection in doing it locally and pushing it to the origin.

I tried things like:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master
```

to set **master** as the default branch within the hosted repo to no avail, so am unsure if I got the wrong end of the stick here.

I'm still a git toddler here so be easy on me if I missed something blindingly obvious!

Comment: The default branch is TFS/VSTS/GitHub feature and not, I think, part of Git. You can set the default branch in the UI on the website.

Comment: Yeah, I know you can do it via the UI, I'm trying to find a solution via the command line though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There isn't any way to set a Default branch on a TFS Hosted Repository with REST API or command line for now.

Check the [Git command reference](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/command-prompt#branches), the Git command line for setting a default branch in your Team Services/TFS repo is still on the web access (Select the settings icon on the web, then select the Version Control tab. Select your Git repository, then select the ... next to the branch name and choose Set as default branch).

Answer (score 1):

As this is not a feature of Git, but of the platform hosting it ( in this case TFS), you need to use the API of that platform to do this. You will not be able to use git.exe.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview

Bot all of the API's are available on TFS.

Comment: Yup, aware of that as well but couldn't find the requisite API call to make a branch a default.

Comment: It might not be available in TFS... What version are you using.

Comment: Er, 2017 as specified in the question title...!

Comment: Looks like that API is not publically available yet. You should request access through http://visualstudio.uservoice.com

Comment: I assume you mean that, whilst the API is public, the call I need is not (or at least not documented), right?

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, in future please don't change titles of questions when there's no need to. Granted I misspelled repository, however taking 2017 out the title and assuming the tag sufficed was not well received. Consensus on meta is that that should NOT have been deleted.

Comment: Sorry, my understanding is that if its in a Tag then it should be removed from the title.